# MSTest empty directory after test deleted

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit test (using MSTest in VS2008 or VS2010) where I create a folder like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    string newdir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "WorkingRoot");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newdir);
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

During the test when I set a breakpoint at the assert, I see that the folder has been created in the specific run folder of MSTest. But when the test has been finished, the folder has been deleted. Why?

Comment: What does `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsTest seems to delete **empty** directories after execution.