# Why wouldn't a folder exist after you create it?

Tags: c#

This doesn't seem to make sense, so I'm obviously doing something wrong:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Test");

if (folder.Exists == false) {
    folder.Create();

    var doesItExists = folder.Exists;
}
```

Creates a folder if it doesn't exist. Except `doesItExists` is always false. Why would it be false if I just created it?

Comment: What is folder? Directory class doesn't have a create method and File.Create needs a filename parameter

Comment: It is probably an instance of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`

Comment: What is `folder`, how do you create it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The value in `folder.Exists` is [cached](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f2e440450e8b52317f08c21fe66f70141c9e933c/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/DirectoryInfo.cs#L117). I would suggest doing this check:

```
var doesItExists = Directory.Exists(folder.FullName);
```

Or you could call `folder.Refresh()` to update the cache before checking if the directory exists after creating it. See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331673/188246).

Comment: Especially if it doesn't refresh it after the `Create` method is called.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that `folder` is a `DirectoryInfo` or `FileSystemInfo`, it reads its values once, and then returns cached values. It doesn't notice that you've created the directory. Call `Refresh()`.

Alternatively use `Directory.Exists()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you would want something like this cached?

Comment: @sircodesalot performance, or maybe the designers were too lazy to implement an event model for that.

Comment: @sircodesalot believe it or not, it is cached and this is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 4):

this will get you true,you need to call refresh():

```
            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Test");

            if (folder.Exists == false)
            {
                folder.Create();
                folder.Refresh();

                var doesItExists = folder.Exists;
            }
```